# Why can we continue reviewing despite lack of flags left

Tags: support

I just consumed all my flags for today. However, I can still continue reviewing questions.

Doesn't that encourage wrong usage of "Requires Editing" instead of "Unsalvagable"? Or are we supposed to "Skip" instead of flag? Leaving such a decision to users doesn't seem safe to me...

Why can we continue reviewing despite the fact that we have no flags left to flag with?

Comment: You're supposed to skip instead of flagging or voting if you don't have any flags or votes left, yes. It shouldn't take too long before you never run out of flags, though.

Comment: We have review choices other than flagging.  So long as I find posts that fit those categories, I use them; I skip the ones I would have flagged.  With thousands of reviewers we get the job done quickly enough.